# Nothing gets sent to Arduino from Processing

Tags: string, performance, arduino, hex, processing

I have a problem where I kwow that my bluetooth module (HC-05) is connected to a processing sketch, but nothing ever gets sent from the processing sketch,why?

No error messages but the info never gets sent over because I never see it in Arduino, where it would be printed to the Serial Monitor.

Full Processing Code:

```java
import processing.serial.*;
import controlP5.*;

Serial myPort;
ControlP5 cp5;

int slider1 = 0;
int slider2 = 0;
int slider3 = 0;

void setup() {


  size(800, 800);
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  PFont roboto = createFont("Roboto-Bold.ttf", 1, true);
  ControlFont font = new ControlFont(roboto, 28);
  Controller Aslider1 = cp5.addSlider("slider1")
    .setPosition(85, 100)
    .setCaptionLabel("Red")
    .setRange(0, 255)
    .setWidth(191)
    .setHeight(50);
  cp5.getController("slider1").getValueLabel().setFont(font).align(ControlP5.LEFT, ControlP5.BOTTOM_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0);
  cp5.getController("slider1").getCaptionLabel().setFont(font).align(ControlP5.RIGHT, ControlP5.BOTTOM_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0);

  Controller Aslider2 = cp5.addSlider("slider2")
    .setPosition(301, 100)
    .setCaptionLabel("Green")
    .setRange(0, 255)
    .setWidth(191)
    .setHeight(50);
  cp5.getController("slider2").getValueLabel().setFont(font).align(ControlP5.LEFT, ControlP5.BOTTOM_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0);
  cp5.getController("slider2").getCaptionLabel().setFont(font).align(ControlP5.RIGHT, ControlP5.BOTTOM_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0);

  Controller Aslider3 = cp5.addSlider("slider3")
    .setPosition(517, 100)
    .setCaptionLabel("Blue")
    .setRange(0, 255)
    .setWidth(191)
    .setHeight(50);
  cp5.getController("slider3").getValueLabel().setFont(font).align(ControlP5.LEFT, ControlP5.BOTTOM_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0);
  cp5.getController("slider3").getCaptionLabel().setFont(font).align(ControlP5.RIGHT, ControlP5.BOTTOM_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0);


  myPort = new Serial(this, "COM5", 9600);
}


void draw() {
  background(255, 100, 100);

  fill(255);
  stroke(1);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(width/2, 350, 200, 75);

  fill(0);
  textSize(32);
  text("Send", width/2 - textWidth("Send") / 2, 350 + 10);

  if (mouseX > width/2 - 100 && mouseX < width/2 + 100 && mouseY > 350 - 75/2 && mouseY < 350 + 75/2) {
    if (mousePressed) {
      fill(100);
      stroke(1);
      rectMode(CENTER);
      rect(width/2, 350, 200, 75);

      fill(0);
      textSize(32);
      text("Send", width/2 - textWidth("Send") / 2, 350 + 10);
    } else {
      fill(170);
      stroke(1);
      rectMode(CENTER);
      rect(width/2, 350, 200, 75);

      fill(0);
      textSize(32);
      text("Send", width/2 - textWidth("Send") / 2, 350 + 10);
    }
  }
}

void mouseReleased() {
  if (mouseX > width/2 - 100 && mouseX < width/2 + 100 && mouseY > 350 - 75/2 && mouseY < 350 + 75/2) {
    fill(100);
    stroke(1);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(width/2, 350, 200, 75);

    fill(0);
    textSize(32);
    text("Send", width/2 - textWidth("Send") / 2, 350 + 10);

    println(hex(color(int(slider1), int(slider2), int(slider3))).toString().substring(2));
    myPort.write(hex(color(int(slider1), int(slider2), int(slider3))).toString().substring(2));
    myPort.clear();
  }
}
```

Full Arduino Code:

```c
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

const int PIN = 6;
const int NUMPIXELS = 30;

const byte rxPin = 2;
const byte txPin = 3;
SoftwareSerial mySerial (rxPin, txPin);

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

unsigned long currentMillis;
unsigned long loopMillis;
unsigned long waitMillis;
int interval = 100;
int waitInterval = 0;
int redBrightness = 0;
int greenBrightness = 0;
int blueBrightness = 0;
bool wait = false;
bool goToRed = true;
bool goToOrange = false;
bool goToYellow = false;
bool goToGreen = false;
bool goToAqua = false;
bool goToPurple = false;

String hexValue;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  pixels.begin();
  pixels.show();
}

void loop() {

  if (mySerial.available() > 0) {
    hexValue = mySerial.read();
    Serial.println(hexValue);
    if (hexValue != "shiftN" || hexValue != "shiftY") {
      shiftMode = false;
      // value is a hex
      redBrightness = hexValue.substring(0, 2).toInt();
      greenBrightness = hexValue.substring(2, 4).toInt();
      greenBrightness = hexValue.substring(4, 6).toInt();
    } else {
      if (hexValue = "shiftY") {
        shiftMode = true;
      } else {
        shiftMode = false;
      }
    }
  }

  pixels.show();

  setColor(redBrightness, greenBrightness, blueBrightness);

}

void setColor(int red, int green, int blue) {
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMPIXELS; i++) {
    pixels.setPixelColor(i, red, green, blue);
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help, cheers!

Other links:

https://discourse.processing.org/t/nothing-gets-sent-to-arduino-from-processing/13654

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/68233/nothing-gets-sent-to-arduino-from-processing

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?board=11.0

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `myPort` is an output stream, it may be buffered. If so, try flushing it after writing:

```
myPort.flush();
```

Comment: What does a port being buffered mean?

Comment: it says the function flush does not exsist

Comment: What is the class of `myPort`? And what class is `hex()` from? If it’s your method, please show its code.

Comment: Hex is being run with an argument that is an int and the class of myPort is Serial

Answer (score 0):

check if hc-05 9600 baud or 38400 baud

Answer (score 0):

For everyone wondering, here is updated code:

Arduino:

```c
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

const int pin = 6;
const int numOfPixels = 30;

int r = 0;
int g = 0;
int b = 0;

Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels(numOfPixels, pin, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pixels.begin();
  pixels.show();

  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  pixels.show();

  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {

    Serial.println(String(Serial.read()));

    r = Serial.parseInt();
    g = Serial.parseInt();
    b = Serial.parseInt();


    setColor(r, g, b);
  }


    serialFlush();

}

void setColor(int red, int green, int blue) {
  pixels.fill(pixels.Color(red, green, blue), 0, numOfPixels);
  Serial.println("Red");
  Serial.println(red);
  Serial.println("Green");
  Serial.println(green);
  Serial.println("Blue");
  Serial.println(blue);
}

void serialFlush() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char t = Serial.read();
  }
}
```

Processing:

```java
import processing.serial.*;
import controlP5.*;

Serial myPort;
ControlP5 cp5;

int slider1 = 0;
int slider2 = 0;
int slider3 = 0;

void setup() {


  size(800, 800);
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  PFont roboto = createFont("Roboto-Bold.ttf", 1, true);
  ControlFont font = new ControlFont(roboto, 28);
  Controller Aslider1 = cp5.addSlider("slider1")
    .setPosition(85, 100)
    .setCaptionLabel("Red")
    .setRange(0, 255)
    .setWidth(191)
    .setHeight(50);
  cp5.getController("slider1").getValueLabel().setFont(font).align(ControlP5.LEFT, ControlP5.BOTTOM_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0);
  cp5.getController("slider1").getCaptionLabel().setFont(font).align(ControlP5.RIGHT, ControlP5.BOTTOM_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0);

  Controller Aslider2 = cp5.addSlider("slider2")
    .setPosition(301, 100)
    .setCaptionLabel("Green")
    .setRange(0, 255)
    .setWidth(191)
    .setHeight(50);
  cp5.getController("slider2").getValueLabel().setFont(font).align(ControlP5.LEFT, ControlP5.BOTTOM_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0);
  cp5.getController("slider2").getCaptionLabel().setFont(font).align(ControlP5.RIGHT, ControlP5.BOTTOM_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0);

  Controller Aslider3 = cp5.addSlider("slider3")
    .setPosition(517, 100)
    .setCaptionLabel("Blue")
    .setRange(0, 255)
    .setWidth(191)
    .setHeight(50);
  cp5.getController("slider3").getValueLabel().setFont(font).align(ControlP5.LEFT, ControlP5.BOTTOM_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0);
  cp5.getController("slider3").getCaptionLabel().setFont(font).align(ControlP5.RIGHT, ControlP5.BOTTOM_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0);


  myPort = new Serial(this, "COM4", 9600);
}


void draw() {
  background(slider1, slider2, slider3);

  fill(255);
  stroke(1);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(width/2, 350, 200, 75);

  fill(0);
  textSize(32);
  text("Send", width/2 - textWidth("Send") / 2, 350 + 10);

  if (mouseX > width/2 - 100 && mouseX < width/2 + 100 && mouseY > 350 - 75/2 && mouseY < 350 + 75/2) {
    if (mousePressed) {
      fill(100);
      stroke(1);
      rectMode(CENTER);
      rect(width/2, 350, 200, 75);

      fill(0);
      textSize(32);
      text("Send", width/2 - textWidth("Send") / 2, 350 + 10);
    } else {
      fill(170);
      stroke(1);
      rectMode(CENTER);
      rect(width/2, 350, 200, 75);

      fill(0);
      textSize(32);
      text("Send", width/2 - textWidth("Send") / 2, 350 + 10);
    }
  }
}

void mouseReleased() {
  if (mouseX > width/2 - 100 && mouseX < width/2 + 100 && mouseY > 350 - 75/2 && mouseY < 350 + 75/2) {
    fill(100);
    stroke(1);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(width/2, 350, 200, 75);

    fill(0);
    textSize(32);
    text("Send", width/2 - textWidth("Send") / 2, 350 + 10);

    myPort.write(str(slider1) + " " + str(slider2) + " " + str(slider3));
    println(str(slider1) + " " + str(slider2) + " " + str(slider3));
  }
}
```

Then look at this link:
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=634061.0